# backup and restore sqlite database with JSON in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, backup, restore, sqflite

In my flutter app, I store data in sqlite database. I want to have a backup and restore feature for these local data in server. What is an efficient way to get all data from all tables from database and send theme as JSON to server? and also what's the best way to save receiving json data to sqlite database?

Can anyone help?

A simple way is using for loop to iterate all tables, but I think it isn't the only way.